# category whose hom-sets is preordered or partially orders

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I have a particular problem of handling category whose hom-sets are preordered (symmetric, transitive but not-always antisymmetric). In other words, I want to investigate the following situation. Let $X$ be a category and $x$, $y$ be objects of $X$. each hom-set $X(x,y)$ is preordered by $\le_{x,y}$.
I am wondering if there is a general theory of such categories so that I can construct my theory on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing can be called a category [enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) over preorders, or a [locally posetal $2$-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+posetal+2-category) (I guess it should be "locally preordered" but "locally posetal" is probably a better search term), or a [$2$-poset](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-poset) (again, I guess it should be "$2$-preorder" but this is probably a better search term), or a [$(1, 2)$-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n%2Cr%29-category), depending on taste. I'm not aware of a general theory but those might be helpful search terms.

Comment: Thank you very much, Qiaochu! It must be helpful!